# How to achieve ​con­cate­na­tive inheritance in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to achieve ​con­cate­na­tive inheritance in Typescript for interface?

Let say I have an interface `Animal`, and I want to override its property `die` with an interface `Dog` from `string` to `boolean`

```js
interface Animal {
    die: string
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
    die: boolean
}

const me: Dog = {
    die: true
}
```

This would give me an error like this:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ts-node-fm/src/index.ts:226
    return new TSError(diagnosticText, diagnosticCodes)
           ^
TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
index.ts:5:11 - error TS2430: Interface 'Dog' incorrectly extends interface 'Animal'.
  Types of property 'die' are incompatible.
    Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

How can I achieve what I want, extending and overriding the original interface in Typescript like how object could be extended in Javascript?

```
const animal = {
 die: 'hello"
}

const dog = {
...animal,
die: true
}
```

Comment: What you're showing is not concatenative inheritance. If anything, it's the opposite, it's the classical OO top-down approach, as opposed to the intended bottom-up approach that concatenative inheritance takes.

Comment: Parameterize `Animal`. `interface Animal<TDie = string> { die: TDie; } interface Dog extends Animal<boolean> { }`. Having suggested that, your use of inheritance seems convoluted and you may have an X-Y problem on your hands

Comment: @VLAZ Thank you for your comment. Would you like to show a simple example for concatenative inheritance? I though what I shown their was concatenative inheritance instead of OO inheritance and I am confused.

Comment: @JohnWinston [here is an article about it](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/the-heart-soul-of-prototypal-oo-concatenative-inheritance-a3b64cb27819). Concatenative inheritance simply refers to grabbing to otherwise unrelated objects and combining them. E.g., `c = {...a, ...b}` would be an example. The two objects are "concatenated" and you get a new object that "inherits" both of them. That's it. Having a `Dog extends Animal` is top-down inheritance where you're structuring your hierarchy upfront rather than deriving it from combining objects.

Comment: @AluanHaddad fully agreed. If `Dog` doesn't conform to `Animal` then the inheritance is not correct. It's saying that dogs are animals, but dogs also don't share the same traits as animals. It's a paradox and an early sign of the OO abstraction being designed wrong.

Comment: @VLAZ thank I get your point now. Is it possible to concatenate interfaces like `c = {...a, ...b}` in Typescript?

Comment: @JohnWinston that would be `type C = A & B` but if your types contradict each other, you don't get anything useful out of them. Which is correct, as concatenative inheritance works with items that are either *different* or overlap meaningfully.

Comment: @VLAZ Good point. If you would write your explanation as Answer, I would love to mark them as corret.

Answer (score 0):

You can narrow the superinterface's members' types down:

```
interface Animal {
  happy: string | boolean;
}

interface Dog extends Animal {
  happy: boolean;  // dogs are simple beings
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Omit`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittype-keys) to remove the property and then overwrite it that way.

```
interface Animal {
    die: string
}

interface Dog extends Omit<Animal, 'die'> {
    die: boolean
}

const me: Dog = {
    die: true
}
```

This will omit the `die` property so that you can reimplement it again essentially overwriting the property.

You need Typescript 3.5 or above to do this.

Comment: But if I have to extend and override more than 1 property, I guess this is quite cumbersome?

Comment: I don't think it's that bad, if you need to override multiple properties you can use `Omit<Animal, 'die' | 'anotherProp'>` to omit multiple types.

Comment: @NilsKähler I'd disagree on "it's not that bad". IMO this suggests fundamental problem with the hierarchy if you cannot directly extend the parent class. Yes, it's simple to add an `Omit` but it's a band-aid solution that exposes the flawed design.

Comment: @VLAZ my comment about it not being bad refers to his comment about it being cumbersome, it was not a reference to the use of it. I guess this is an example code snippet, seeing the data is pretty simple, so I'm would not try to make comments about if it's a flawed hierarchy design without more information.